# I cannot append my data to a list

Tags: python, arcpy, cursors

I am trying to append the total area to the attribute table and it runs through without any error message. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
import os
import arcpy
import math
folderpath = 'C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173'
arcpy.env.workspace = folderpath
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
input_shp = folderpath + r'\lower48_county_2012_election.shp'
equal_shape = folderpath + r'\project_lower48.shp'

projection = arcpy.SpatialReference('USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic USGS')
arcpy.Project_management(input_shp, equal_shape, projection)
print 'step 1'

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (input_shp, equal_shape)
tot_area = []

print "step 2"
fields = [
    ("totarea", "FLOAT"),
]

for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(equal_shape, "totarea")
print "step 3"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(equal_shape, ("OID@", "SHAPE@AREA")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
    print("Feature {0} has an area of {1}".format(row[0], row[1]))
print "step 4"

a_cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(equal_shape)
for area in a_cursor:
    tot_area.append(area.totarea,)
print "step 5"
```

Update:
wnnmaw when I run the code it runs and prints a list of the features/polygon's area but when I open the .shp file the new column is there, and none of the data appends to the list.
ZWiki When I print the list it returns a huge list of 0's like what is listed in the attribute table. In the code I classify it as a FLOAT however in arcmap attribute table properties it still is identifying it as LONG, could this be the problem since the answers are decimals?

Comment: What is the *specific* issue you are encountering?  Please include the list you're trying to append, any relevant output, and what you have tried so far to solve the issue

Comment: Well my guess here would be that `arcpy.SearchCursor` is returning an empty list then, or returning something that you are not expecting. Can you print that and tell us what it returns?. Also, you should either escape the backslashes in `folderpath` or give it as a raw string like you did `input_shp` and `equal_shape`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: You've got a data type issue when you're adding that list of fields.

This code simply adds a field named `totarea`, and doesn't do anything with the data in the `fields` list.

```
for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(equal_shape, "totarea")
```

Instead:

```
fields = [("totarea", "FLOAT")]
for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(equal_shape, field[0], field[1])
```

---

Secondly: [Use an UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm). Search cursors don't have the ability to change the table's data.

If you want to stick with that list of areas:

```
tot_area = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(equal_shape, ("OID@", "SHAPE@AREA")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print("Feature {0} has an area of {1}".format(row[0], row[1]))
        tot_area.append(row[1])
print "step 4"

sum_area = sum(tot_area)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(equal_shape, ["TOTAREA"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = sum_area
        cursor.updateRow(row)
print "step 5"
```

Or just sum as you go through the SearchCursor:

```
tot_area = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(equal_shape, ("OID@", "SHAPE@AREA")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print("Feature {0} has an area of {1}".format(row[0], row[1]))
        tot_area += row[1]
print "step 4"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(equal_shape, ["TOTAREA"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = tot_area
        cursor.updateRow(row)
print "step 5"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried to use the first and the sum but every polygon has a value of 0, 1, or 2 . The area though is 0.300735193692 is there a way to append the decimal values to the attribute table?

Comment: As long as the `TOTAREA` field is of type float, you should be able to append decimals.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have made sure it's a float and it always populates the field with the same value 817.129. Any feedback would be much appreciated

Comment: What area exactly are you trying to put in that field?

Comment: I was trying to put the`"SHAPE@AREA"` into that field

Comment: Is there a reason you need it in a separate field? Anyway, just do an update cursor with both the source and target attributes, then set `row[1] = row[0]` instead of the sum of the area, and skip the search cursor entirely.

Comment: Yeah  we need the aarea and centroid coordinates to make a centroid. Do I just get rid of the entire search cursor?

Comment: The only reason to have it would be to sum the area of all features in the feature class. Your question wasn't well phrased so I didn't really know what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Sorry for the poor wording.